# Trigger to update all records with same data

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a column named 'Ratio' in my table. Which I want to use to store the value of the ratio of the items with respect to the total value at a specific date.

The problem I'm facing is that the trigger only changes the ratio of one row (NEW.row) and leaves the values of the rest alone. But when one value changes I want them all to change since it is a ratio.

This is what I have so far;

```
CREATE TABLE `item_table` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    `Name` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Value` DECIMAL(7 , 6 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Ratio` DECIMAL(7 , 6 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE 
    TRIGGER  `ins_ratio`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `item_table` FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW . `Ratio` = NEW.`Value` / (SELECT 
            SUM(`Value`)
        FROM
            `item_table`
        WHERE
            Date = NEW.Date);
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: Or don't store ratio - calculate as and when needed..

Comment: ^^ A much better solution ^^

Comment: Your trigger does not take into account the row to be inserted. This prevents correct insertion - new Ratio value will be NULL always. And it won't recalculate in previous rows. Agreed with @P.Salmon - do not store overdefined data, calculate when needed.

Comment: I normally wouldn't store ratio but I need to use the ratio value in another calculation down the line. And I hoped splitting it would make things less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER  `ins_ratio`
BEFORE INSERT ON `item_table` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`Ratio` = NEW.`Value` / (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`Value`), 0) + NEW.`Value`
                                 FROM `item_table`
                                 WHERE `Date` = NEW.`Date`);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e387a87a05422afec40ecad070e78627

Pay attention - your `Ratio` is cumulative, not recalculational.

Comment: This query does not address my primary concern which is that the ratio columns don't all update once a value is changed. This shows in the ratio of the first column of the fiddle being 1.00.

Comment: @danielajj I have told this explicitly: "Ratio is cumulative". If you want to assign new ratio value to all rows then you cannot do this in a trigger. Use stored procedure instead of INSERT query. But it's best to follow P.Salon's advice.